# Get Model Type from RazorView object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, razor

I have a System.Web.Mvc.RazorView object which is strongly typed when in cshtml.

Can I get the model type from an instance of this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible.

Call `BuildManager.GetCompiledType(view.ViewPath)` to get the type generated by compiling the view.
You can find the model type by checking the generic argument of the compiled type's base type (which should be `WebViewPage<TModel>`)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get the model given only an instance of a `System.Web.Mvc.RazorView`. It's available inside the `RenderView` method which is passed a `ViewContext` but from the outside you can't access it. But if you are inside a view you could use the `Model` property.

Comment: You could invoke the build engine and get the base type.

Comment: Thanks Darin.
SLarks, what do you mean by the build engine?